# Linkedin Omniauth Won't Work on Safari

Tags: heroku, safari, linkedin-api, omniauth

LinkedIn Omniauth is working on chrome and firefox, but every time I try to run it in Safari, it doesn't work. The app works locally but breaks on production only. The app is deployed to Heroku.

Even stranger, I have both Airbrake and New Relic set up and they are not recording the error.

I have a Ruby on Rails app that's deployed to heroku.  Here are the logs:

```
2015-01-15T22:34:37.545497+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2015-01-15T22:34:37.545399 #6]  INFO -- omniauth: (linkedin) Callback phase initiated.
2015-01-15T22:34:37.537878+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/auth/linkedin/callback?oauth_token=XXX&oauth_verifier=XXX" for 50.161.71.219 at 2015-01-15 22:34:37 +0000
2015-01-15T22:34:38.164715+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/auth/linkedin/callback?oauth_token=XXX&oauth_verifier=XXX" host=glassbreakers-prototype.herokuapp.com request_id=8b48a139-4dd4-4b70-b665-bba8e92162f7 fwd="50.161.71.219" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=621ms status=401 bytes=912
2015-01-15T22:34:38.150147+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2015-01-15T22:34:38.149476+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
2015-01-15T22:34:38.149487+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"oauth_token"=>"XXX, "oauth_verifier"=>"XXX", "provider"=>"linkedin"}
2015-01-15T22:34:38.150006+00:00 app[web.1]: Filter chain halted as #<Proc:0x007fab17cc76c0@/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/http_authentication.rb:71> rendered or redirected
2015-01-15T22:34:38.151927+00:00 app[web.1]: source=rack-timeout id=8b48a139-4dd4-4b70-b665-bba8e92162f7 wait=3ms timeout=5000ms service=615ms state=completed
2015-01-15T22:34:38.520198+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/auth/linkedin/callback?oauth_token=XXX&oauth_verifier=XXX" host=glassbreakers-prototype.herokuapp.com request_id=68e1211b-a48c-4b99-9d81-48fb9cc9de0c fwd="50.161.71.219" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=62ms status=302 bytes=771
2015-01-15T22:34:38.461750+00:00 app[web.1]: source=rack-timeout id=68e1211b-a48c-4b99-9d81-48fb9cc9de0c wait=9ms timeout=5000ms state=ready
2015-01-15T22:34:38.465810+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2015-01-15T22:34:38.465701 #14]  INFO -- omniauth: (linkedin) Callback phase initiated.
2015-01-15T22:34:38.518223+00:00 app[web.1]: source=rack-timeout id=68e1211b-a48c-4b99-9d81-48fb9cc9de0c wait=9ms timeout=5000ms service=57ms state=completed
2015-01-15T22:34:38.462592+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/auth/linkedin/callback?oauth_token=XXX&oauth_verifier=XXX" for 50.161.71.219 at 2015-01-15 22:34:38 +0000
2015-01-15T22:34:38.515655+00:00 app[web.1]: E, [2015-01-15T22:34:38.515527 #14] ERROR -- omniauth: (linkedin) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth::Problem, parameter_absent
2015-01-15T22:34:38.759075+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/auth/failure?message=invalid_credentials&strategy=linkedin" host=glassbreakers-prototype.herokuapp.com request_id=325b4bc6-4127-40b6-b693-5df84fc17bbf fwd="50.161.71.219" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=9ms status=301 bytes=467

2015-01-15T22:34:38.995281+00:00 app[web.1]: source=rack-timeout id=767d5c33-4dc3-42ff-bdf6-b318b8dba784 wait=20ms timeout=5000ms service=13ms state=completed
2015-01-15T22:34:38.752063+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/auth/failure?message=invalid_credentials&strategy=linkedin" for 50.161.71.219 at 2015-01-15 22:34:38 +0000
2015-01-15T22:34:38.981976+00:00 app[web.1]: source=rack-timeout id=767d5c33-4dc3-42ff-bdf6-b318b8dba784 wait=20ms timeout=5000ms state=ready
```

Comment: Seems like the error has to do with `Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth::Problem, parameter_absent`.  Perhaps this issue is related to http://stackoverflow.com/a/3039620/1949363 and perhaps solved by https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/issues/622 or https://github.com/decioferreira/omniauth-linkedin-oauth2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had basic HTTP Auth on my application and for some reason Safari treats it differently than Chrome or Firefox.  Once I turned off http auth, the omniauth linkedin worked fine on Safari.