# What is the correct Oauth method to access JIRA API?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin

I have tried the method here [Jira Oauth](https://www.redradishtech.com/display/KB/How+to+write+a+Python+script+authenticating+with+Jira+via+OAuth) and also [Oauth Helper](https://github.com/cyriptix/atlassian-oauth-helper).

I am trying to use Python to generate the oauth access token but have ran into the following issues so far:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "./atlassian-oauth-helper.py", line 36, in 
>       fetch_response = oauth.fetch_request_token(base_url)
>     File "/Users/user/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth1_session.py", line 287, in fetch_request_token
>       token = self._fetch_token(url, **request_kwargs)
>     File "/Users/abhuiyan/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth1_session.py", line 369, in _fetch_token
>       raise TokenRequestDenied(error % (r.status_code, r.text), r)
>   requests_oauthlib.oauth1_session.TokenRequestDenied: Token request failed with code 400, response was 'oauth_parameters_absent=oauth_consumer_key&oauth_problem=parameter_absent'.

I have found a description of the error above  [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935441/oauthproblem-parameter-absent), however I am following the guides above and sending the request parameters.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.redradishtech.com/display/KB/How+to+write+a+Python+script+authenticating+with+Jira+via+OAuth is from Jeff Turner. Good stuff!